# How to correctly dispose spweb and spsite on powershell foreach!

Tags: powershell, dispose

Title of the question is pretty simple, I have 18000 site collections and this script is showing 1GB of ram used, so I wonder how can I dispose correctly the spweb and spsite object

```
$webapplication =  Get-SPWebApplication  http://xxx
foreach($site in $webapplication.Sites)
{         

    foreach($subWeb in $site.AllWebs)
    {
        if($subWeb.AllProperties["WebTemplate"] -eq "Client" -or $subWeb.AllProperties["WebTemplate"] -eq "Job")
        {

           if($subWeb.AllProperties["WebTemplate"] -eq "Client")
           {
                $infoList  = $subWeb.Lists["Client Info"]
           }

           if($subWeb.AllProperties["WebTemplate"] -eq "Job")
           {
                $infoList  = $subWeb.Lists["Job Info"]
           }

           if($infoList -ne $null)
           {              
               $InfoItem = $infoList.Items[0]
               if($InfoItem -ne $null)
               {
                  $clientCode = $InfoItem["Client Code"]

                  $quicklaunchnavigationnodes= $subWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch
                  foreach($navNode in $quicklaunchnavigationnodes)
                  {
                      if($navNode.Title.Contains("Tax Invoices"))
                      {
                        $clientcodefromurl = $navNode.Url.Substring($navNode.Url.IndexOf("=")+1,8)

                        if($clientCode -ne $clientcodefromurl)
                        {
                            Write-Host 'Processing  site ' $subWeb.Url 
                            Write-Host '  Info list found for ' $subWeb.Url 
                            Write-Host '  Info item found '
                            Write-Host '    Client code from url: ' $clientcodefromurl                          
                            Write-Host '    There is a difference' -ForegroundColor Red 
                            Write-Host '    Incorrect Navigation Url: ' $navNode.Url                           
                            Write-Host '    New Url: ' $navNode.url.Replace($clientcodefromurl, $clientCode)
                            #$navNode.url.Replace($clientcodefromurl, $clientCode)
                            #$navNode.Update()
                            Write-Host '    Url updated' -ForegroundColor Green 
                        }
                      }                
                  }
               }
               else
               {
                     Write-Host '  Info item not found '$spWeb.Url 
               }           
           } 
           else
           {
               Write-Host 'Info list not found for ' $subWeb.Url 
           }  
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> When you close the PowerShell.exe process, the memory is freed. If you
>   need to dispose objects to keep memory pressure down (important in
>   production environments or if you're looping over all sites/webs),
>   make sure to dispose. If not, you don't need to worry about disposing.
>
> The reason why we're so crazy about disposing in the first place is
>   because most SharePoint code runs in long-running processes (either in
>   an ASP.NET worker process or OWSTimer.exe) and failing to dispose can
>   cause difficult-to-troubleshoot, sudden catastrophes (i.e., web server
>   go boom). These catastrophic performance issues/OutOfMemoryExceptions
>   don't affect me most of the time when working in PowerShell. I run
>   ad-hoc scripts, I waste ~3-50MB of RAM because I fail to dispose my
>   objects, I close the PowerShell window and the memory is freed. Most
>   of the time it's a nonissue.
>
> You can built scripts for working with SharePoint using the below
>   links,
>
> [Here is a script wherein I dispose SPSite and SPWeb objects](http://poshcode.org/1251)
>
> [Here is a script in which I don't bother to dispose an SPSite
>   object](http://poshcode.org/1304)
>
> [How can I dispose SharePoint objects safely in PowerShell functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789177/how-can-i-dispose-sharepoint-objects-safely-in-powershell-functions)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999858/how-bad-is-it-to-not-dispose-in-powershell)

I strongly recommend you to have a look at the below link

[Best Practices: Using Disposable Windows SharePoint Services Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248.aspx)

You can also form your script as per the below script,

```
foreach ($site in $wa.Sites) {
 foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
  #Put your functionality
  $web.Dispose()
 }
 $site.Dispose()
}
```